# How Can I Put the Heading in a while loop only for individual result not for Duplicate results?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Vehicle num    total_amount
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500
TEST w 785     1000
TEST w 785     1000
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700
```

But i want to like this.

```
Vehicle num    total_amount
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500
TEST V 1234    500


Vehicle num    total_amount
TEST w 785     1000
TEST w 785     1000


Vehicle num    total_amount
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700
TEST Z 589     700
```

I want to display the headers above for each group vehicle wise.

```
  <?php

#other code

$track = null;
$total = 0;

while ($fet_all = mysql_fetch_array($query_all)) :?>    
  <?php if ($track !== null && $track !== $fet_all['truckk_number']): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Vehicle No:</td>
        <td><?php echo $track; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
        <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $total = $fet_all['total']; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php $total += $fet_all['total'];  ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <tr class="accord-content even bg-gray" style="color:#698602 !important;">
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['ownername']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['truckk_number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fet_all['total']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php $track = $fet_all['truckk_number']; //add this line ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php if ($total > 0): ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Vehicle No:</td>
        <td><?php echo $track; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total:</td>
        <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you have so far? What have you tried?

Comment: Are the duplicates always contiguous?

Comment: Added my Code, any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
$v = false;
while ($row = someReadFunction()) {
    if ($row["vehicle"] != $v) echo "Write header here...";
    echo implode (" ", $row); // Or your preferred way to display it.
    $v = $row["vehicle"];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\n)(([^\n]*)(?:\n\2)*)
```

You can try this.Replace by `Vehicle num    total_amount\n$1\n\n`.Just strip the header or remove the first line.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/10

```
$re = "/(?<=\\n)(([^\\n]*)(?:\\n\\2)*)/i"; 
$str = "TEST V 1234    500\nTEST V 1234    500\nTEST V 1234    500\nTEST w 785     1000\nTEST w 785     1000\nTEST Z 589     700\nTEST Z 589     700\nTEST Z 589     700"; 
$subst = "Vehicle num    total_amount\n\1\n\n"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```